# I am getting an error while trying to install kali tools in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I was referring this site for installation I got this error -"fatal: destination path 'katoolin' already exists and is not an empty directory.
" while executing this command-"git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git  && cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin". Please help I've just started using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just means that the directory you are trying to populate with *git* is already existing. You have to delete/rename it.

Try either this (to rename):

```
mv katoolin katoolin.old
```

or this (to delete, but make sure it does not contain important data)

```
rm -rf katoolin
```

then re-run your command.